# How can a React component measure an unknown number of children individually, then modify layout based on height

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I'm looking for a way to have a component render all of it's children, measure their heights, then modify the layout based on those heights. For example, say I have a Document component that contains several (and unknown quantity) Paragraph components. I want the Document component to be able to measure those Paragraphs and insert a horizontal rule where a page break would go.

**Before layout:**

```
<Document pageSize="A4" layout="portrait">
    <Paragraph text="some long text" />
    <Paragraph text="some long text" />
    <Paragraph text="some long text" />
    <Paragraph text="some long text" />
    <Paragraph text="some long text" />
    <Paragraph text="some long text" />
</Document>
```

**After layout:**

```
<Document pageSize="A4" layout="portrait">
    <Paragraph text="some long text" />
    <Paragraph text="some long text" />
    <hr /><!-- End of page 1 -->
    <Paragraph text="some long text" />
    <Paragraph text="some long text" />
    <Paragraph text="some long text" />
    <hr /><!-- End of page 2 -->
    <Paragraph text="some long text" />
</Document>
```

I can get each Paragraph component measure itself using the `useClientRect()` hook from the Hooks FAQ, but I don't know how to get the Document component to access that height. Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

I would also like to clarify that I'm looking to provide visual feedback on screen about where page breaks will be when printing, akin to the feedback provided by Google Docs or MS Word.

Comment: Hi @BrentParker, I just wrote you a solution, let me know if that helps!

Comment: @ChristopherNgo I just read your solution. I think you've figured it out. I'm going to give it a shot and implement it. You have no idea how much I appreciate it. If I get it to work I'll mark it as the accepted answer, and if not I'll be back to ask more questions. Thanks a lot, Christopher!

Comment: You're welcome man! And awesome I really hope it works for you.

Comment: Any luck with integrating this solution?

Comment: Sorry, I have a day job teaching and have had class all morning so I haven't had a chance to try, yet. I have been reading through it during every break though, thinking about how it would be converted to hooks.

Comment: Oof that is tough! I mean I can create a hooks example for ya too, but I figured you might wanna try that out for yourself :)

Comment: I do want to figure it out myself! I was actually trying something kinda similar to your solution (passing a callback to children for them to add heights to the parent) but never got it working right. The parent useEffect hook seemed to be called before the children had finished rendering because the parent div was reporting a height of 32px while all the children had heights much larger. I'll scrap what I've already written and stick much closer to what you wrote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem kept me up all night. But I think I found a solution that should work for you.

Essentially, you need to give each `Paragraph` component a `ref`. The `ref` will have info on the height on the entire component. You then just need to pass that height back-up to the `Parent` component that contains the `Document` component.

Upon receiving all the heights from the Paragraphs, you can calculate a `runningHeight` to dynamically add your `PageBreaks`. In this case, page-breaks are just `<hr>` tags that are conditionally added within each `Paragraph` component.

See working sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/dynamically-adding-pagebreaks-fjvfl

Main code:

**App.js**

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import Document from "./Document";
import Paragraph from "./Paragraph";
import data from "./data.js";

import "./styles.css";

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    pageBreak: 500,
    heights: [],
    breaks: []
  };
  updateHeight = height => {
    this.setState(
      prevState => {
        return {
          heights: [...prevState.heights, height]
        };
      },
      () => {
        this.setBreaks();
      }
    );
  };

  setBreaks = () => {
    const { heights, pageBreak } = this.state;
    const breaks = [];
    let runningHeights = [];

    let runningHeight = 0;

    heights.forEach((height, index) => {
      if (index === 0) {
        runningHeight = height;
        runningHeights.push(runningHeight);
        if (runningHeight >= pageBreak) {
          breaks.push(true);
        } else {
          breaks.push(false);
        }
      } else if (index > 0) {
        if (runningHeights[index - 1] < pageBreak) {
          runningHeight = runningHeights[index - 1] + height;
          runningHeights.push(runningHeight);

          if (runningHeight >= pageBreak) {
            breaks.push(true);
          } else {
            breaks.push(false);
          }
        } else {
          runningHeight = height;
          runningHeights.push(runningHeight);
          if (runningHeight >= pageBreak) {
            breaks.push(true);
          } else {
            breaks.push(false);
          }
        }
      }
    });

    this.setState({
      breaks: breaks
    });
  };

  render() {
    const { breaks } = this.state;
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Document>
          {data.map((item, index) => {
            return (
              <Paragraph
                text={item.text}
                updateHeight={this.updateHeight}
                break={breaks[index]}
              />
            );
          })}
        </Document>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

**Paragraph.js**

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";

const Paragraph = ({ text, updateHeight, ...props }) => {
  const paragraphRef = React.createRef();
  useEffect(() => {
    updateHeight(paragraphRef.current.offsetHeight);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div ref={paragraphRef}>
      {text} {props.break && <hr />}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Paragraph;
```

**Document.js**

```
import React from "react";

const Document = props => {
  return <div>{props.children}</div>;
};

export default Document;
```

Comment: This totally worked. I need to fiddle with some CSS and make things more attractive, but that's minor.

Comment: @BrentParker that's awesome man! I'm glad this worked for you :)

Answer (score 1):

I've done something similar recently using the below code. I wasn't setting standard page sizes and inserting HRs, rather getting a bunch of tiles to set their heights to be the same. However, it might point you in the right direction...

```
export const standardiseTiles = (className) => {
    const nodes = [...document.getElementsByClassName(className)];

    nodes.forEach(n => {
        n.style.height = 'auto';
    });

    const maxHeight = nodes.reduce((p, c) => {
        return c.clientHeight > p ? c.clientHeight : p;
    }, 0);

    nodes.forEach(n => {
        n.style.height = `${maxHeight}px`;
    });
};
```

I'm calling this in componentDidUpdate passing in the class name of the parent container.

Not perfect but it's working.

Hope it helps!

Comment: This is interesting. I was trying to keep everything within React components and hadn't really considered using pure javascript. It looks promising. I'll give it a shot and update! Thanks!